# Pandasのインストールについて

Tags: python, pandas, pip

`pip install pandas` をすると、

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pandas
```

と、出てしまいうまくいかず、
https://qiita.com/tkinoshi726/items/5184ce80e888262f5da1
によると、

`--no-build-isolation`というオプションを付けるとうまくいくらしいですが、

`no such option: --no-build-isolation`と出てしまい、うまくいきません。

原因は何でしょうか？宜しくお願いします。

Python : 2.7.10
pip : 9.0.1
OS : Mac

Comment: 最新バージョンのpandasだと依存関係が、'python-dateutil >= 2.5.0', 'pytz >= 2011k', 'numpy >= 1.9.0' なので、まず pip freeze でそれらのインストールされているバージョンを調べてみたらどうですか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、pip と setuptools のバージョンを最新のものにしましょう。

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

多分それでインストールできるようになると思うのですが、できなければ`pandas`の依存関係が、'python-dateutil >= 2.5.0', 'pytz >= 2011k', 'numpy >= 1.9.0' なので、それらのバージョンを同じようして上げてください。

なお、オプションを設定せずに`pip install pandas`とした場合は、`wheel`の`package`が使われるので`Cython`は必要ありません。参考にしたQiitaの記事は、`No matching distribution found for Cython`となっていますが、今回は`No matching distribution found for pandas`であるので参考にはなりません。また、`--no-build-isolation`が使えるのは、`pip 10`以降です。（ [pip リファレンスガイド](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#pep-518-support) ）pandasのコンパイルに`pip 10`以降が使われていると思われるので`pip`のバージョンを先に最新のものにしてみましょう。